# PHP - how to crawl external url using get or post method and parse json data from it?

Tags: php, json, curl, zend-framework2

I have one server running with ZF2 and i have another client with PHP, now from client i need to read the json output via get or post method.

How to crawl external link form client and parse the JSON data to read the value of 'result' => $msg?

Client: http://www.other-end-user.com/view:

```
<?php
$customerid = $_GET['id'];
$id = substr('3' . rand(0,9999), 0-$length);
$default = "https://toogle.com?id={$id}";
$b = "<a href={$default} id={$customerid}button class={$customerid}button><img src=\"http://toogle.com/button.png\" /></a>";

#curl "http://www.external-analytics-site.com/ajax/json" | grep result
$live = true
if ($live){
  echo $b;
} else {
  echo "Live query failed";    
}


?>
```

Server (ZF2): http://www.external-analytics-site.com/ajax/json:

```
class AjaxController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function jsonAction(){
      $response = $this->getResponse();
      $msg = true;        
      $json = array(
        'result' => $msg,
        'module' => 'ajax',
        'data' => "test"
      );
      $response->setContent(Json::encode($json));
      return $response;            
      exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to look at `Zend Http Client` (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.client.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use
[file-get-contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
to read from the server via GET

you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to parse the result

Comment: Is it fast enough? to handle millions of requests `file-get-contents()` i mean?

Comment: fast enough compared to what ? where you planning to [shell_exec("curl ...")](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: So its fast enough compared to shell_exec right? then would be great.

Comment: You could always try both methods and measure which is faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_content to get json data .. but If you need content of page too..

```
 function crawl_page($url, $depth = 5)
{
    $saved = array();
    if (isset($saved[$url]) || $depth === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $saved[$url] = true;

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $element) {
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
            $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
            if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                $href = http_build_url($url, array('path' => $path));
            } else {
                $parts = parse_url($url);
                $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) {
                    $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                }
                $href .= $parts['host'];
                if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                    $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                }
                $href .= $path;
            }
        }
        $this->crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
    }
    echo "URL:",$url,PHP_EOL,"CONTENT:",PHP_EOL,$dom->saveHTML(),PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL;
}
```